# How to record video with low audio quality

Tags: ios, swift, audio, video

I am working on a project, we want to minimize the size in the sound part of a video. I know we can use ACAudioSession to record a pure audio, and can set the quality detailed into sampling rate, number of channels.

But when I want to design a video taker which record records audio at the same time. I found for the AVCaptureSession, I can only set the quality of video and audio together using sessionPreset, which leads the quality of video and audio decrease at the same time.

I am wondering whether there is a way to keep the video in high quality while manage to reduce the size of audio when taking a video?

Appreciate for the help.

Comment: As a follow up, I finally give up to set different quality for sound and video. While the main reason is the sound size is really negligible compare with video size.